# Criar uma propriedade para uma variavel bool que trate string e int

Tags: c#, propriedade

Estou criando um projeto em que busco as informações do banco de dados, no caso é um arquivo DBF, e o campo é do tipo Logical. Porem quero criar uma propriedade que possa receber uma variável (seja int, string ou bool) e grave na variável privada bool.

Já tenho métodos que recebem int (0/1) e transformam em (True/False) e que recebem string (T/F | V/F | S/N) e transforma em (True/False). Mas gostaria de fazer o tratamento quando estivesse "setando" o valor do campo.

Tentei criar 3 propriedades com cada tipo de dados, mas quando vou utilizar ele fala que há mais de uma propriedade com o mesmo nome. (Que seria nesse caso).

```
public override int Vip
{
    get { return clsGeneric.convertFromBool(vip); }
    set { vip = clsGeneric.convertToBool(value); }
}
public override string Vip
{
    get { return clsGeneric.convertFromBool(vip,clsGeneric.TypeRetBool.TF); }
    set { vip = clsGeneric.convertToBool(value); }
}
public override bool Vip
{
    get { return vip; }
    set { vip = value; }
}
```

E agora está assim:

```
public override TipoGenérico Vip
{
    get { return vip; }
    set
    {
        if (value.GetType() == typeof(string))
        {
            vip = clsGeneric.convertToBool((string)value);
        }
        else if (value.GetType() == typeof(int))
        {
            vip = clsGeneric.convertToBool(value);
        } else {
            vip = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Queria fazer com que a propriedade aceitasse tanto Int, quanto string e Bool. Há algum meio de fazer isso?

> **Edit:** O resultado ficaria dessa forma?

```
Class DBPort
{
    private bool vip;
    public LogicalValue Vip
    {
        get { return vip; }
        set { vip = value.Value; }
    }
    public DBPort()
    {
        Vip = false;
    }
```

}

Comment: Dessa forma não funciona?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não é possível fazer a sobrecarga(*overload*) de propriedades.
Terá de criar uma classe que encapsule esse comportamento, qualquer coisa assim:

```
public class LogicalValue
{

    public bool Value { get; }

    public LogicalValue(int value)
    {
        Value = clsGeneric.convertToBool(value);
    }


    public LogicalValue(string value)
    {
        Value = clsGeneric.convertToBool(value);
    }

    public LogicalValue(bool value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

<sub>Nota: Deverá adicionar aos construtores algum tipo de validação.</sub>

A sobrecarga do construtor permite construir objectos *LogicalValue* a partir de um *int*, *string* ou *bool*.

O seu código ficaria assim:

```
Class DBPort
{
    public LogicalValue Vip { get; set;}

    public DBPort()
    {
        Vip = new LogicalValue(false);
    }

}
```

A utilização seria assim:

```
DBPort dpPort = new DBPort();
dbPort.Vip = new LogicalValue(true);ou (1) ou ("S")

bool valorVip = dbPort.Vip.Value;// valorVip é igual a true
```

Comment: Eu não entendi como posso utilizar essa classe para setar o valor na propriedade

Comment: A sua propriedade em vez de ser do tipo `bool` passa a ser `LogicalValue`. Para "setá-la" faça `nomeClasse.NomeProp = new LogicalValue(aqui pode ser ser bool ou int ou string);` para obter o valor faça `bool valor = nomeClasse.NomeProp.Value;`

Comment: Peço desculpa pela ignorância, mas continuo sem entender, na questão eu coloquei o código (desculpe-me caso não esteja nos padrões daqui)

Comment: Veja a edição à resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar duas propriedades uma do tipo Objct e outra bool, a primeira servirá de base para seta o value da outra.

```
namespace stackoverflow
{
    public partial class AlterarTipo : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private bool vip { get; set; }
        public  object Vip
        {
            get { return vip; }
            set
            {
                if (value.GetType() == typeof(string))
                {
                    vip = Convert.ToBoolean(value);
                }
                else if (value.GetType() == typeof(int))
                {
                    vip = Convert.ToBoolean(value);
                }
                else {
                    vip = Convert.ToBoolean(value);
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Vip = "false";
            Vip = 1;
            Vip = true;
            Vip = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Esta resposta não é boa. Ela viola o SOLID e o `get` é inseguro.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, faça uma melhor, terei o prazer de ver como pode ser feito.

Comment: [Já foi feito](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/145488/2999). Minha sugestão é tipar fortemente a propriedade `Vip`, ao invés de um `object`.